# Inserting data from one SQL Table to another based on some checks

Tags: sql, excel, merge

I have a SQL Table with columns like *Ref#,EndDate,StepRespone, StepName*. The data is being populated daily in SQL Table using an excel file. 
Now i want to use the existing SQL table as a *staging table* because i want to do some massaging and filteration on the data.
I want to transfer the data into another table and if the StepName is BureauPull i want to map the *Enddate* with *Login_Date* and if the *StepName* is L2 i want to Map it with Decision_Date. Ref# is the unique column and if the record is not availble in the new table then i want to insert the data as it is and if it is available then i want to perform above checks.
I have tried using Merge and have constructed the following query but it is giving me syntax error.

```
MERGE od_test2 T --tareget
USING OD_TEST S --source
ON (S.ref = T.REF)
WHEN MATCHED 
THEN UPDATE
SET T.LOGIN_DATE = 
(CASE 
WHEN s.stepname IN ('BUREAUPULL') THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR,s.[ENDDATE]) 
ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR,s.[LOGIN_DATE]) 
END S.LOGIN_DATE),
T.Decision_DAte = (CASE 
WHEN s.stepname IN ('l2','l3') THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR,s.[ENDDATE]) 
ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR,s.[DECISION_DATE]) 
END S.DECISION_DATE)

WHEN NOT MATCHED
THEN INSERT (Target_Column_Names)
VALUES (Source_Column_Names)
```

There may be any other way of doing this instead of using Merge but i am unsure of it. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is my first ever answer here so I might be very off target. Have you tried JOIN (- INNER JOIN - LEFT JOIN - RIGHT JOIN).

Comment: No, basically i dont think joins will work here ( i maybe wrong) because i am inserting from 1 SQL table to another and only some columns will get updated based on StepName. And if the record is new that is not available in new table then the row will get inserted as it is

Comment: Ok, I see. Then yes, JOIN may not help you much.